# Implicit Any error for an explicit any field

Tags: typescript

I am declaring explicitly a field as any type but then I get compile error that the field is implicitly any !

Here is the code:

```
export const errorManager = (d: any) => {
    if (d.__typename === "Error") {
        if (d.errors)
            throw new InputValidationError(d.message, d.errors)
        throw new Error(d.message)
    }
    return d;
}
```

The error is

```
Parameter 'd' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7006
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter `d` doesn't have a type, you need to give it a type such as

`(d: string) =>`
or
`(d: number) =>`
or whatever you need. Otherwise the compiler won't know what `d` really is